# How to recover LXD containers inside a zfs pool?

Tags: 16.04, server, lxd

I have this setup:

sda : ubuntu server 16.04

sdb and sdc : a zfs pool

I have several LXD containers, during the lxd init, I selected zfs and supplied a zfs dataset for lxd to use.

now I have this situation: sda is down, sdb and sdc is fine. I need to install ubuntu server 16.04 in a new hard disk, question is, how to access the lxd containers from this newly installed sda?

Thanks,